# Replace url in all hrefs inside body tags

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I am using cfhttp to get a website . I want to replace all the links inside the body tags. Importantly I don't want to mess up the stylesheets etc in the head.

I want to do the following:

In the external web page body we may find a link:

```
<a href="http://www.externallink.com">External Link</a>
```

I want to replace it with the following:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com?url=http://www.externallink.com">External Link</a>
```

Its easy enough using Replace() but then I also replace all the linked stylesheets etc. I just want to edit the href's of clickable links.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  To make your code look like code, put 4 spaces in front of it.

Comment: Can you post a small snippet of the HTML code you want the replaces in.

Comment: use jQuery something like  `$("a").attr("href", "http://new address");`

Comment: Actually I could bypass the need to do this if I can find a way to get the URL of a frame (cross-domain). Can this be done with postmessage?

Comment: Why not describe what you are _actually_ trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Let me explain. I have two frames and I need to know the url of the main frame. The bottom frame contains content from the web. The top frame allows the user to "bookmark" the URL of the bottom frame. The top frame needs to know the URL of the bottom frame as user moves around the web. This is part of an Intranet. Because of the problems with getting the URL because it's across domains, I thought that if I load the external web page through cfhttp and then replace all the URL's on the page then I can at all times get the URL that the user has clicked on.

Comment: How are the frames built?  Iframes, frameset, etc.

Comment: @Miguel-F it's a Frameset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified an HTML document's DOM to add tracking parameters to links in outbound email messages using the jsoup library.  (jsoup is an open source Java HTML Parser and can be download at http://jsoup.org/.)  You'll note that it uses jQuery-like select methods, but all manipulations are performed on the server-side  (I've also used it for removing ads from CFHTTTP-fetched HTML.)

Here's a quick sample of working ColdFusion code that will do exactly what you want on the server-side:

```
<CFSET TheHTML = CFHTTP.FileContent>
<CFSET jsoup = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup")>
<CFSET TempHTML = jsoup.parse(TheHTML)>
<CFLOOP ARRAY="#TempHTML.select('a')#" INDEX="ThisLink">
    <CFSET TheLink = thisLink.attr("href").toString()>
    <CFSET TheHTML = replace(TheHTML, TheLink, "http://mywebsite.com/?u=" & URLEncodedFormat(TheLink))>
</CFLOOP>
```